# Typescript declaration for Node module package

Tags: typescript, type-declaration, typescript-declarations, typescript-definitions

I'm trying to add a TS delcaration for a package i'm using.
The package itself doesn't have any TS declarations.

I'm using VS Code, and it throws the warning

```
 Try `npm i --save-dev @types/picoapp` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'picoapp';`
```

So i added the following to reference methods build in. In a `Picoapp.d.ts` file

```
declare module 'picoapp' {
  export type Context = {
    on: (event: string | string[], method: CallableFunction) => void,
    emit: (event: string | string[], data?: object | Function) => void,
    hydrate: (object: object) => void,
    getState: () => any,
  };
}
```

But with above, and using the Context reference, it insists on importing the Context from the package like this:

`import { Context } from 'picoapp'`
How do you get around that, seems risky that it attaches itself on the package... Just thinking in case of they adding a method called **Context** later on, then what happens